# Get DateTime Obj from "mm/yyyy" format Date string

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a date string in format "08/1999" I want to get the first date of the corresponding month. eg : in this case 08/01/1999. 
It is simple for en-Us culture. I break the string, append "01" in the string to get 08/01/1999 and then DateTime.Parse(datestring) but this is valid for en-US culture only.

How can I do this for different culture ?

My datestring will always be in mm/yyyy format. and I am trying to obtain a DataTime obj from this dateString.

Comment: Is this a C# question? If so, please specify this in your tags, you will get the right people interested more quickly. Well, maybe.

Comment: Do you have another culture in mind?  Not sure what type of application language you are using, but it maybe able to convert dates and time based off of the setting on the server\pc.

Comment: It would be easier to do it with string manipulation in the en-GB culture, as you only have to add `01/` to the beginning.  Much more sensible.... However the answers below are much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method. Note upper-cased M's are for months and lower-cased m's for minutes.

```
string dateToConvert = "08/1999";
string format = "MM/yyyy";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToConvert, format, provider);
```

Output:

```
{1999-08-01 00:00:00}
```

You can also use Convert.ToDateTime and Parse methods. It will produce the same result, but in implicite way:

```
DateTime result = Convert.ToDateTime(dateToConvert, provider); // Output: {1999-08-01 00:00:00}
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(dateToConvert, provider); // Output: {1999-08-01 00:00:00}
```

Read more at:

- [Parsing Date and Time Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> I break the string, append "01" in the string to get 08/01/1999 and then DateTime.Parse(datestring)

That's a very long-winded way to do it. Simply this will work:

`DateTime.Parse("08/1999")`

> How can I do this for different culture ?

If your string is always in this format, do this:

`DateTime.Parse("08/1999", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can try passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you want to force the US date format regardless of the regional settings of the client computer:

```
DateTime.Parse("08/1999", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```